# Can we sequentially optimize a function that is convex but not jointly convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, non-convex-optimization

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$ where $f$ is convex in $x$ and $y$ but not in $(x,y)$. Suppose that for a fixed $y$, the minimization over $x$ lands on a solution that doesn't depend on $y$, e.g.

$$
\bar x = \arg\min_x\; f(x,y), \quad \forall y.
$$

Then I also find 
$$
\bar y(x) = \arg\min_y \; f(x,y).
$$
Is $(\bar x, \bar y(\bar x)) = \arg\min_{x,y}\; f(x,y)$?

**Application**: I'm trying to understand the maximization step in the Gaussian mixture models. Here, we want to find

$$
(\mu, C) = \arg\min_{\mu, C} \; \underbrace{\sum_i -z_i \log \det(C) + z_i (x_i-\mu)^TC (x_i-\mu)}_{f(\mu,C)}
$$
The standard answer gives

$$
\bar \mu = \frac{\sum_i z_i x_i}{\sum_i z_i}, \qquad \bar C = \frac{\sum_i z_i (x_i-\bar \mu)(x_i-\bar \mu)^T}{\sum_i z_i}
$$
which is exactly what would happen using the procedure I outlined above, but it doesn't seem like this function is jointly convex in $\mu$ *and* $C$. 
In fact, in the 1-D 1-sample case, the Hessian is 
$$
\frac{\nabla^2 f(\mu,C)}{z_i} = \left[\begin{matrix} C & x-\mu \\ x-\mu & C^{-2}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
which, well, isn't necessarily positive semidefinite.

Maybe my interpretation is off?

Thanks all!

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Suppose $f(x^\star, y^\star) < f(\bar x, \bar y(\bar x))$. Then certainly $x^\star \neq \bar x$, because $f(\bar x, \cdot)$ is minimized by $\bar y(\bar x)$. But this means that $\arg \min_x f(x, y^\star) \neq \bar x$. That's a contradiction. Thus, $(\bar x, \bar y(\bar x))$ is a minimizer for $f$.

Comment: I think you're right. the unique structure of $x^*$ being independent from $y$ is how we get away from it.